# How to show a view with a side by side comparison of Knowledge Articles?

Tags: lightning-knowledge

I wish to compare the last published version of a Knowledge article with the corresponding unreleased draft, as these are often very long and hence it is very difficult to spot what the change was in the new version before sending them to approval.

So far I have found almost nothing about this feature except [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l3T7AAI) that somewhat resembles my requirement but we can not wait till that development is completed.

I have found [this article](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_knowledge_versions.htm) too however what we need is a left and right view pane (like eclipse etc) with insertion deletion etc to compare between 2 versions of document.

I have not found any relevant App in Appexchange too.

Any pointers on how to proceed will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 20 might brings this feature [Compare Versions of an Article to See What Changed (Beta)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_knowledge_compare_versions.htm)

> Knowledge users can compare two versions of an article to review changes. The Article Version Comparison app component lets authors choose a version to see the differences.
>
> **As of now Spring 20 is still in preview, note the following:**
> As a beta feature, Article Version Comparison is a preview and isn’t part of the “Services” under your master subscription agreement with Salesforce. Use this feature at your sole discretion, and make your purchase decisions only on the basis of generally available products and features.